# Ear(s) making a muffle sound during high intensity weight training sessions

Tags: health, breathing, hiit

This happens almost every time when I do high intensity interval training (HIIT). Even though I'm a physical therapist and a master trainer, I still can't really figure this out. I've read online that this could due to the fact that I may not breathe properly, especially during really high intensity workout sessions.

Has anyone experienced ear popping or making a muffle sound with each breath during weight training sessions, especially during HIIT with weights? It does go away a few minutes after each session.

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced similar symptoms during CrossFit metcon style workouts where I'm breathing heavily in conjunction with lifting moderately heavy weights. The sensation is not unlike the blocked/muffled ears you experience during take-off or landing when flying (but without the discomfort).

I spoke to my GP about it and his assessment was that it sounded like [Pulsatile Tinnitus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinnitus#Pulsatile_tinnitus) caused by changes in my blood pressure while lifting (and potentially exacerbated by me losing concentration and paying less attention to my breathing during the lift than I should).

I do have periods of higher than normal resting blood pressure, so a quick blood pressure check might be something to investigate. I still occasionally get the weird ear symptom when my resting blood pressure is normal however.

Comment: Very Interesting. I do have normal resting blood pressure however. I think this phenomenon is similar to a few more people that I've recently came across, and they all said the same thing. Let's just hope it's more due to improperly breathing during HIIT...

Comment: I just did my HIIT workout, and this time I really focused on my breathing technique (in my nose and out my mouth and as regular as possible). I didn't experience this phenomenon just then. Perhaps for me at least is the breathing technique.

Comment: @QikMood, it's a shame automatic blood pressure monitors are so bulky and require inflation - I'd love to wear one while I'm lifting to confirm the ear noise perfectly correlates to a jump in my blood pressure. Anecdotally my findings are the same as yours and it's only when I get sloppy with the lifts and breathing that I get the muffled symptom. Thanks for the update - it's nice to know I'm not the only one that suffers from it.